# Getting JSON parse error on JSON property createdAt when not included in request body

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am recently learning to build REST APIs with Kotlin and Spring Boot. I was trying to create my first domain model and controller end-point. Here is the implementation of the Country model and CountryController countroller.

/model/Country.kt

```
package com.example.example.model

import jakarta.persistence.Column
import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType
import jakarta.persistence.Id
import jakarta.persistence.Table
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener
import java.sql.Timestamp


@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
class Country (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    val id: Int,
    val code: String,
    val displayName: String,

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    val createdAt: Timestamp,

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    val updatedAt: Timestamp
)
```

/controller/CountryCountroller.kt

```
package com.example.example.controller

import com.example.example.model.Country
import com.example.example.repository.CountryRepository
import jakarta.validation.Valid
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping

@RestController
class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var countryRepository: CountryRepository

    @PostMapping("/countries", consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun createCountry(@Valid @RequestBody country: Country): Country {
        return countryRepository.save(country);
    }


}
```

Schema of the Country table:

```
  country_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  code VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  displayName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (country_id)
```

When I started running the Spring Boot application and use Postman to call the POST /countries API, I received a 400 Bad Request error. The application error log says:

`2023-01-12T14:09:15.423Z  WARN 90037 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.example.example.model.Country] value failed for JSON property createdAt due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter createdAt which is a non-nullable type]`

The request body is a json and the request header has include the correct Content-Type information:

```
{
    "code":  "FRA",
    "displayName": "France"
}
```

I suspected that the Spring Boot did not ignore the two fields `createdAt` and `updatedAt`, therefore I have tried to add @JsonIgnore above createdAt and updatedAt. Unfortunately the same 400 Bad Request error was still returned.

Do I actually have to include createdAt and updatedAt in the JSON request body? However, what I wanted to achieve is that the createdAt and updatedAt should be added/updated either by the Spring Boot application putting the createdAt and updatedAt data when calling the repository methods or by MySQL DB when the query is being run. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two concepts here

1. whether on not `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are allowed be **null** in your data model
2. **serialization**:

   - whether you want the `RestController` to deserialize the fields when you receive them in the POST
   - whether you want the `RestController` to serialize the fields when you implement a GET request

By using `@JsonIgnore` (or the Kotlin variation `@set:JsonIgnore` you are just avoiding the data deserialization but still the data model requires a value.   The JPA annotations are going to get executed when you put the data in the database, but in the time that the object is created by the MVC infrastructure, and before the database save happens, the data does not match the model contract.

There are two solutions to what you want to do:

#### Relax the data model

Change your data model to allow nulls in the two fields:

```
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    val createdAt: Timestamp?,

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    val updatedAt: Timestamp?
```

BTW I would expect you to get the error on `id` as well, perhaps an Exception would be given for that once you dealt with the two dates, because again, your POST data does not supply id and this not nullable.

#### Use a Request object

Create a simpler data model that is used to receive your POSTed data and then create the Domain/Database model object from it.

I use a mix of the two techniques depending on circumstances.  The latter approach has benefit, e.g. when you have large objects which may only be partially sent by the client (think PATCH).

Comment: Thanks for your clean explanation. One question to follow up: After I have changed my data model to allow nulls in id, createdAt and updatedAt fields, given that I have the annotation "@GeneratedValue", "@CreatedDate" and "@LastModifiedDate" for the fields respectively, should I expect a record with id=1 (given that the table is empty), createdAt={current time} and updatedAt={current time} inserted into the table? Do I need extra work to make sure createdAt and updatedAt are included before the object is inserted to the table? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dexter, I am 80% sure these can left null and Spring Data will take care of them.  Try it!  Possibly you need to enable an audit feature.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have made the changes and tried to see if it works. I am now getting a 500 Internal Server Error. While I believe this is a different issue, I would like to see if you possibly know how to fix it. I am now getting this error in the log: 
`[nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineScope] with root cause`

 I am guessing if I have missed any dependencies, do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments. I have successfully solved the above problem by adding the kotlinx.coroutines dependency. Now I am facing the following error 
`org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.example.example.model.Country.createdAt` Do I have to supply createdAt and updatedAt value or did I misunderstand the error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, that error is different to the one in your original post.  You can see the error class is `...Hibernate...` and if your annotation still says `@Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)` then you need to change that `nullable = true`.  Again there are lots of different concepts you are crossing: `@Column` nullability is different from the Kotlin nullability and the JSONProperty thing, and it is also different feature from `@LastModifiedDate`

Comment: I have tried to change it into `nullable = true` but I am now getting a new but similar error from java.sql: `Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'updated_at' cannot be null` Interestingly it is referring to `updated_at` but not `created_at`. My understanding is that `@LastModifiedDate` does put the value during record creation. Am I thinking in the wrong direction? Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: Ok, so next layer down is the Database.  Sometime with the original `nullable=false` code, the JPA/Spring data created your tables in the database.  It would have configured them to have mandatory fields.  If you drop your database (or configure Spring to regenerate the schema) maybe it will work for you.  Perhaps in all this we've gone too far; you want to rely on the fact that created/updated are always present.  So there must be another way you can populate the Data Object with a not-null placeholder that the JPA/Spring framework then overwrites due to the Annotation.  Need #jpaexpert now

Comment: Oh, now I see the DDL for the database in the OP - did you write that... you see it has `Create table.... updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ...` (but not on `created_at`)... QED on that point.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have tried to update the schema and removed the `NOT NULL` from `updated_at` column. Now the API returns OK 200 with the JSON of the created record. However, I notice that createdAt and updatedAt are both null in the DB, which is not what I wanted and expected. Do I have to manually set the value in Spring Boot to have the current time as the value for both createdAt and updatedAt. Initially I thought `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` would do what I wanted but it seems like it was not the case.

Comment: Fyi, I have already added `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation in the Application class, in attempt to enable automatic auditing.